# What’s a good translation for “Stand Up Guy”?

Tags: translation, phrase

Looking less for a literal translation than something that carries the same meaning, i.e. a dependable, well-meaning person.

Comment: https://dict.leo.org/forum/viewUnsolvedquery.php?idThread=1110784

Comment: Von denen? "Patenter Kerl" am ehesten mMn.

Answer (score 3):

A translation more in line with the usage might be **Pfundskerl**, meaning an honest, great guy. It's not overly common in everyday language.

Answer (score 0):

Eine **aufrichtige Person** oder **ein verlässlicher, loyaler Freund**.

Comment: Ist ein Freund nicht immer loyal? Oder, wenn er nicht loyal ist, ist er dann noch ein Freund?

Comment: _aufrichtig_ is an almost literal translation of _stand-up_ and fits well, but it‘s probably better combined with a different noun, e.g. _Typ_ or _Kumpel_. The other phrase is the *description* found at dict.cc and not a proper translation as is.

Comment: @Robert Ein Freund zu sein artikuliert sich in eier soziologischen Beziehung der Zuneigung und sympathisches Verhältnis. Loyalität muss nicht immer gegeben sein. Es gibt schließlich, leider Gottes, auch schlechte Freunde.